# Difference between ftp apache setDefaultimeout() , setSoTimeout() and setDataTimeout()

Tags: java, apache, ftp, timeout

The following blog  explains about the ftp apache commens net libaray's different timeout viz setDefaultTimeout(),setSoTimeout(),setDataTimeout().

http://sudhirvn.blogspot.in/2007/05/ftpclient-timeout-values.html

But please clarify my following doubts WRT the above mentioned timeouts?

a)Does setSoTimeout() sets timeout only for ftp control connnetion and not data connection ?

b)Does setDataTimeout() sets timeout only for ftp data connection and not control connection ?(I am asking this because it uses the underlying java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout() )

c)If we set setDefaultTimeout() ,then we dont need set/use setSoTimeout() and setDataTimeout() ?since the blog says that  'setDefaultTimeout() is used default for all connections made using this FTPClient instance.'

d)Also do we need set connection timeout ? if we dont set it ,will the program rely on opearting system connection timeouts ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6):

The three methods all trigger a call to setSoTimeout() at the socket level.

setDefaultTimeout() is called **prior** to connecting and passes the timeout value to socket.setSoTimeout() for all future control connections.  The default is 0, which means infinite timeout.  FTPClient.setSoTimeout() is used **after** a connection is established as an override to the current socket SO_TIMEOUT setting and applies only to the current control connection socket.

setDataTimeout() sets the timeout for reading from the data connection.  Looking at the code, a value of 0 is essentially the default (infinite wait).

You would only want to call these methods if you want something different than the default timeout (infinite).

I determined all this from reading the docs and checking the source code, so if someone sees something wrong with what I said, please correct me.